# From Data Set to Textbox in VB.Net using MS-Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, dataset

```
Private Function Gelobee() As DataSet
    Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=CMP.accdb"
    connection.Open()
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT IDDesc FROM [ItemDesc] WHERE " & PartNoTxt.Text & " ORDER BY IDID;", connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "FilteredDesc")
    Return ds
    connection.Dispose()
    connection = Nothing
    DescTxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(1)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Gelobee()
End Sub
```

I am trying to get the result of the query in Function Gelobee to go to DescTxt.Text when I click the Button1. When I click the Button1, nothing appears in the DescTxt. No errors but It wont show the result in the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code stops at the `Return` statement.

Change Gelobee() to this:

```
Private Function Gelobee() As DataSet
    ... ' Removed for brevity

    da.Fill(ds, "FilteredDesc")
    connection.Dispose()
    connection = Nothing
    DescTxt.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item(1)
    Return ds
End Function
```

Comment: I am glad to be able to help.